# How to download files from AWS S3 via CodeBuild

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a build in AWS who get an Automation Project from GitHub and runs it. All the files that we are using to upload to the UI are currently saved to the repo of the project. I don't like it as it is about 300 - 400 MB, and that is a lot. My idea is to use the CodeBuild Buildspec and download the files from AWS S3 to the server before the broject is build. Is this possible at all?

I am new the the CodeBuild so I prefer some guidance. If the whole idea is not possible, I will have to use the project SetUp but there are a lot of things that can break while trying to download the files.

Comment: Just run `aws s3 sync` or `aws s3 cp` in one of the steps in your CodeBuild project.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, but in general you have to generate a buildspec.yaml that instructs AWS CodeBuild to do what you want.

The AWS Documentation is actually pretty good, there are a lot of examples.

[This one](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codebuild-samples/blob/master/buildspec.yml) downloads the source primiarily from S3 and secondary sources from Github. This might fit your use case.

Have a look at the [other examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-case-based-samples.html) as well, they might help generating the buildspec.yaml

If none fits, you will still be able to run normal bash commands and do `aws s3 sync` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

At the end it was just one row that had to be added in the build:

```
  aws s3 cp s3://{folderPath} {path to download} --recursive
```

This will download all files from the folder whatever you need them one by one and will wait for all to download.